# Music services with Last.fm integration?

Tags: webapp-rec, music, last.fm

I used http://thesixtyone.com for quite some time as the main source of new music discoveries. At some point they redesigned their site and it became really hard to use. The old version is still available now but who knows for how long. So I feel like it's time to move on. I also scrobble my music so the integration with Last.fm is quite important for me. Is there any other streaming music service with scrobbling support?

Comment: RIP old version thesixtyone :(  you will be eternally be dearly missed.

Comment: Try [The Hype Machine](http://hypem.com/)!

Answer (score 2):

[Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) is very good and has Last.Fm integration, but is not available outside of Europe yet

Answer (score 1):

The [VIP mode](http://vip.grooveshark.com/) of [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/) offers scrobbling to [Last.fm](http://last.fm)

Answer (score 1):

- [LastPandora](http://www.lastpandora.com/)
- [Blip.fm](http://blip.fm)

Answer (score 1):

[Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/)

> Rdio is a music service, where you
>   discover music through your friends
>   and followers. Rdio works in the
>   browser, on the desktop, and on
>   Android, BlackBerry and iPhone
>   smartphones. Rdio also provides music
>   downloads.

[image]

Comment: as long time Lala user .. this is getting closer every day.